# How to drag and drop a file from desktop to browser

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to automate the code for drag and drop of a file using protractor-cucumber framework with from desktop to the browser,but it couldn't drag the file.Please help me

Comment: show us the code

Comment: Please read this Tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop from desktop to browser is still not supported by protractor. 
You can upload file using the file path as below

```
it('should upload a file', function() {
  var fileToUpload = '../some/path/foo.txt',
      absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

  element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);    
  element(by.id('uploadButton')).click();
});
```

hope it helps you